# rotate 3d point cloud to offset angle of floor plane given vNormal and floor point

Tags: geometry, kinect, openframeworks, openni

I'm working with kinect and ofxopeni. I have a point cloud in real world coordinates but I need rotate those points to offset the tilt of the camera. The floor plane should give me all the information I need but I can't work out how to calculate the axis and angle of rotation.

my initial idea was...

```
ofVec3f target_normal(0,1,0);
ofVec3f vNormal; //set this from Xn3DPlane floorPlane (not shown here)
ofVec3f ptPoint; //as above

float rot_angle = target_normal.angle(vNormal);

for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++){

   cloudPoints[i].rotate(rot_angle, vNormal, ptPoint); //align my points to normal is (0 1 0)                               

}
```

This it seems was too simplistic by far. I've been fishing through various articles and can see that it most probably involves a quarterion or rotation matrix but I can't work out where to start. I'd be really grateful for any pointers to relevant articles or what is the best technique to get an axis and angle of rotation ? I'm imagining it can be done quite easily using ofQuarterion or an openni function but I can't work out how to implement.

best

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used ofxopeni, but this is the best mathematical explanation I can give.

You can rotate any set of data from one axis set to another using a TBN matrix,(tangent, bitangent, normal), where T B and N are your new set of axis. So, you already have the data for the normal, but you need to find a tangent. I'm not sure if your Xn3DPlane provides a tangent, but if it does, use that.

The bitangent is given by the cross-product of the normal and the tangent:

```
 B = T x N
```

A TBN looks like this:

```
TBN = { Tx ,Ty ,Tz,
        Bx, By, Bz,
        Nx, Ny, Nz }
```

This will rotate your data on a new set of axis, but your plane also has an origin point, so we through in a translation:

```
A = {1 , 0 , 0, 0,    { Tx , Ty , Tz , 0,   
     0,  1,  0, 0,      Bx , By , Bz , 0,    
     0,  0,  1, 0,  x   Nx , Ny , Nz , 0, 
     -Px,-Py,-Pz,1}      0 ,  0 ,  0 , 1}    

// The multiply the vertex, v, to change it's coordinate system.
v = v * A
```

If you can get things to this stage, you can transform all your points to the new coordinate system. One thing to note, the normal is now aligned with the z axis, if you want it to be aligned with the y, swap N and B in the TBN matrix.

EDIT: Final matrix calculation was slightly wrong. Fixed.

[TBN calculation.](http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html)

Comment: thanks this makes rotation matrices make much more sense ! Just for reference I ended up using some of the ofVec3f functions which make things slightly easier. Namely get the cross product of the normal and target vectors as axis of rotation. Get the angle between target and normal then rotate all points by this angle around axis at pivot point. Next time I shall use this method though.